# Generate CRLF in TSQL to be accepted by SSRS

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, encoding, newline, xml-entities

In TSQL I concatenate different rows to one cell with: FOR xml path('')
I place the next characters after every line to produce a linefeed. 
+ char(13) + char(10)
SSRS does generate a linefeed but also prints these CRLF characters.
Every line ends with: `&#x0D;`
Is there a solution?

Comment: Characters printed: "&#x0D;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML you produce with a simple `FOR XML PATH('')` (in order to do something like `STRING_AGG()`) will translate any forbidden character (such as `<, > and &` and many more) to the correspondig entity. An entity is `&abc;`, while `abc` stands for a character (like `&lt;`) or you see some kind of hexadecimal or unicode code point. This is done while creating the XML implicity. Reading something out of this XML will do the invers process - again implicitly.

But: Your code **does not return the result as the native XML type**.

Try this (best switch the output to "text"):

```
SELECT TOP 5 o.[name] + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.objects o
FOR XML PATH('')
```

returns

```
sysrscols&#x0D;
sysrowsets&#x0D;
sysclones&#x0D;
sysallocunits&#x0D;
sysfiles1&#x0D;
```

But if you handle the XML as a *typed* result, you can use `.value()`:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT TOP 5 o.[name] + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    FROM sys.objects o
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.','nvarchar(max)');
```

returns

```
sysrscols
sysrowsets
sysclones
sysallocunits
sysfiles1
```

You did not show any code, but I assume that you've got something like

```
SELECT  SomeColumn
      ,(SELECT blah + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
        FROM SomeInnerTable 
        WHERE SomeCondition 
        FOR XML PATH('')) AS SomeAlias
FROM SomeOuterTable;
```

Change this to

```
SELECT  SomeColumn
      ,(SELECT blah + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
        FROM SomeInnerTable 
        WHERE SomeCondition 
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS SomeAlias
FROM SomeOuterTable;
```

Comment: Tx very much. It Works.